# Remove last visited directory in terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, history, rm

The `-` command returns the last visited directory in the terminal. If I try to delete the last directory like that `` rm -rf `-` `` nothing happens. That means the last visited folder still exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beware that `-` is **not a command**, it has the meaning you describe only when used as an argument to the `cd` command (see the OPERANDS section of the [POSIX man page for cd](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1posix/cd/)). If you try to execute it you should get

```
$ `-`
-bash: -: command not found.
```

Note that you do not see the error message because of the `-f` parameter. Remove it and you will get

```
$ rm -r `-`
-bash: -: command not found
usage: rm [-f | -i] [-dPRrvW] file ...
       unlink file
```

**The previous directory is available** in the `$OLDPWD` env variable. So your command should be

```
rm -rf "${OLDPWD}"
```

As a side note `-` also has the special meaning of `stdin` when used as a file name, for many GNU command. And also note that the  backtick construct is deprecated in favour of the `$()` construct.